# Can PowerMockito check arguments with whenNew?

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I have an implementation of some API.

For example:

```
public class SoPostApi implements SoApi {

...

@Override
public void searchOrganizations(String query, ...) {
    String jsonResponse = performPostMethod("SearchOrg", ...);
    ...
}

@Override
public void searchCategories(String query, ...) {
    String jsonResponse = performPostMethod("SearchCat", ...);
    ...
}

private String performPostMethod(String methodName, ...) {
    URL url = new URL(API_URL + methodName);
    ...
}
```

And I want use PowerMockito to test it.

How I see it:

- catch new instance of `URL.class` and return `mocked URL`
- check new instance of `URL.class` argument to contains substring (`methodName.contains("SearchOrg")`, but how?)
- mock `openConnection()` method depending on the `methodName`

For example:

- if method performPostMethod instantiate a new `URL.class` with `String` argument that contains `"SearchOrg"` then I want replace it with `URL` where method `openConnection()` returns `HttpURLConnection` configurated for this argument(`getInputStream()` must return json with a list of organizations).
- if method performPostMethod instantiate a new `URL.class` with `String` argument that contains `"SearchCat"` then I want replace it with `URL` where method `openConnection()` returns `HttpURLConnection` configurated for this argument(`getInputStream()` must return json with a list of categories).

**Is it realizable?**

Comment: Hi @Alexandr, could you check my answer? Did it help you to solve the issue? Le me know if you've any doubt.

Comment: @troig yep, thank you. I very busy and I check it as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do that combining `whenNew(...)` and [thenAnswer()](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html) Mockito capabilities.

Something like the example as follows:

```
  final InputStream inputStreamOrg = null; // Load your Org json input stream
  final URL urlSearchOrg = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
  Mockito.when(urlSearchOrg.openStream()).thenReturn(inputStreamOrg);

  final InputStream inputStreamCat = null; // Load your Cat json input stream
  final URL urlSearchCat = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
  Mockito.when(urlSearchCat.openStream()).thenReturn(inputStreamCat);


  PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withArguments(Mockito.any(String.class))
        .thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
           @Override
           public URL answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
              String spec = (String) invocation.getArguments()[0];
              if (spec.contains("SearchOrg")) {
                 return urlSearchOrg;
              } else if (spec.contains("SearchCat")) {
                    return urlSearchCat;
              } else {
                 // OTher casees
                 return null;
              }
           }
        });
```

*NOTE*: Just note that in your OP you want to mock `openConnection()` method to return an `InputStream`. I think it's a confusion because `openConnection` doesn't return an `InputStream`. I think you are referring to method `openStream()` (my example is mocking this method). Anyway, I think with this example you can see how to do it in a general way.

Hope it helps